# After adding a new kernel module, I am getting an error Unknown symbol btree_lookup

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to add a new module to existing kernel on my machine.
After I compiled and added the module to kernel, modporbe gives me this error

```
[root@localhost linux-3.10.1]# modprobe -f  tcm_qla2xxx
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'tcm_qla2xxx': Unknown symbol in module,        
umknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

The dmesg output is:

```
dmesg | grep tcm_qla2xxx
[252616.940005] tcm_qla2xxx: Unknown symbol btree_last (err 0)
[252616.940027] tcm_qla2xxx: Unknown symbol btree_insert (err 0)
[252616.940080] tcm_qla2xxx: Unknown symbol btree_remove (err 0)
[252616.940119] tcm_qla2xxx: Unknown symbol btree_geo32 (err 0)
[252616.940179] tcm_qla2xxx: Unknown symbol btree_lookup (err 0)
[252616.940194] tcm_qla2xxx: Unknown symbol btree_init (err 0)
[252616.940287] tcm_qla2xxx: Unknown symbol btree_destroy (err 0)
[252616.940302] tcm_qla2xxx: Unknown symbol btree_update (err 0)
[252616.940329] tcm_qla2xxx: Unknown symbol btree_get_prev (err 0)
```

The tcm_qla2xxx file is not mine, so Makefile and actual code should be alright.
I understand, the most possible I am missing some btree file. In kernel source from where I took the tcm_qla2xxx module, there was a btree.c file in lib/ folder.  I am not sure how to add the btree.c file to old kernel without rebuilding the whole kernel.
I do not want to build a new kernel

Thank you

Comment: Kernel 3.10 has `lib/btree.c` file too. For compile this file into kernel, you need to enable `BTREE` configuration option in the kernel, that is, recompile the kernel (the option has a type `boolean`, so you cannot enable the *module* containing it). As for workarounds.. you may try to compile this file into your module instead of the kernel. Or you may try to change type of the option in `lib/Kconfig` from `boolean` to `tristate`, so you may configure your kernel for build this file as a module.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, C'mon, it really doesn't matter since `BTREE` library is exporting symbols to the module(s). So,  since we are talking about ancient kernels we need take into account that the exporting stuff might have been introduced later (I didn't check), though as I can see in **v3.10.y** it's there. So, I would recommend to update the kernel to latest stable release first.